# Learning too slow when I add 2 neurons to the output layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am implementing a neural network from scratch to identify a cat or not which is working just fine.

```
Architecture of neural net is:
Image shape = (64,64,3)
Train images = 100 ==> reshaped too (12288, 100)
Test images = 25 ==> reshaped too (12288, 25)


Layers are as:
[12288, 32, 64, 128, 256, 1024, 1]
Learning rate = 0.01

Cost I get on this is:
Cost after iteration 0: 0.6931489297046624
Cost after iteration 100: 0.4883935590415581
Cost after iteration 200: 0.36081001955698583
Cost after iteration 300: 0.27667037518359366
Cost after iteration 400: 0.21814954139135215
Cost after iteration 500: 0.17566035067079316
Cost after iteration 600: 0.14379510198340753
Cost after iteration 700: 0.11931953624412495
Cost after iteration 800: 0.1001804918888681
Cost after iteration 900: 0.08500294953949178
Cost after iteration 1000: 0.0728255235455732
Cost after iteration 1100: 0.06295421630851546
Cost after iteration 1200: 0.05487653264581672
Cost after iteration 1300: 0.048207823668081726
Cost after iteration 1400: 0.04265587452224586
Cost after iteration 1500: 0.03799651492130658
Cost after iteration 1600: 0.03405630846956158
Cost after iteration 1700: 0.030700016432453042
Cost after iteration 1800: 0.02782139326988321
Cost after iteration 1900: 0.025336361142384353
Cost after iteration 2000: 0.023177909431575435
Cost after iteration 2100: 0.021292256317487622
Cost after iteration 2200: 0.019635942647950454
Cost after iteration 2300: 0.01817361697739766
Cost after iteration 2400: 0.01687633799342948
Cost after iteration 2499: 0.015731194121508994
```

Cost is reducing so the net is learning, but when I modify this net to identify between cat vs. dog, the cost reduction is very small. I replaced output layer with 2 neurons as there are two classes I need to predict cat or dog stats are follows.

```
Architecture of neural net is:
Image shape = (64,64,3)
Train images = 100 ==> reshaped too (12288, 100)
50 images are of cats, 50 are of dogs.
Test images = 25 ==> reshaped too (12288, 25)

Layers are as:
[12288, 32, 64, 128, 256, 1024, 2]
Learning rate = 0.01

Cost I get on this is:
Cost after iteration 0: 1.3862942626917214
Cost after iteration 100: 1.3862936877441023
Cost after iteration 200: 1.3862936382959834
Cost after iteration 300: 1.3862936088999924
Cost after iteration 400: 1.3862935723383438
Cost after iteration 500: 1.3862935546779653
Cost after iteration 600: 1.3862935413933175
Cost after iteration 700: 1.386293531419176
Cost after iteration 800: 1.3862935241175995
Cost after iteration 900: 1.386293501361619
Cost after iteration 1000: 1.3862934905311062
Cost after iteration 1100: 1.386293484867794
Cost after iteration 1200: 1.386293473659006
Cost after iteration 1300: 1.3862934660150443
Cost after iteration 1400: 1.3862934500384458
Cost after iteration 1500: 1.386293442026514
Cost after iteration 1600: 1.3862934342382442
Cost after iteration 1700: 1.3862934290588118
Cost after iteration 1800: 1.3862934193689949
Cost after iteration 1900: 1.3862934103850098
Cost after iteration 2000: 1.3862934054327474
Cost after iteration 2100: 1.386293398123051
Cost after iteration 2200: 1.3862933780745346
Cost after iteration 2300: 1.3862933699459277
Cost after iteration 2400: 1.3862933608537853
Cost after iteration 2499: 1.3862933546832072
```

Cost reduction Is too much slow, any reason why is that?

Comment: what kind of layers are you using? Are you actually using just 50 images of each? That's not enough at all. Why do you have 2 neurons as the output? Use one, with sigmoid function. If it's closer to 0, it's a cat, if it's closer to 1, it's a dog. Or vice-versa.

Comment: Hidden layers are ReLU and ouput layer has sigmoid. Ok I get your idea. But can you tell me how can I achieve like probability on last two neurons for example. I input an image, and first neuron outputs 0.3 telling me 30% probability its a cat and second neuron outputs 0.7 telling me that its a 70% probability its a dog.

Comment: but that's just one output. Why do you need the second neuron, if you can just calculate it as `1 - probability_its_a_cat` ?
https://lindevs.com/classify-images-of-dogs-and-cats-using-cnn-and-tensorflow-2/

Comment: I was going for something like when I have three classes like cat, dog, mouse then you need three neurons right ?  each one giving their own probability of classes. Is it required that you keep 1 neuron when identifying between 2 classes ? What if I do if I have 3 as I stated above ?

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not really sure how multiple classificators would work, I'm new to neural networks.

Comment: Ok no problem. I'll just wait for someone to answer then :D